# pandas DataFrame.plot: how do I get UNIX timestamps on the x-axis as date/time in my local timezone?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, localtime

I'm trying to plot some time series data whose source times are UNIX timestamps (seconds since 1970) and I want to see date/times in my local timezone on the x-axis. I'm using the `DataFrame.plot` method from `pandas`. No matter what I do, I seem to get UTC times on the x-axis. This applies to both the tick labels and their positions.

Here's a demo script:

```
import time
from dateutil.tz import tzlocal
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy import datetime64
from pandas import DatetimeIndex
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

figure = Figure(figsize=(7, 4))
figure.add_subplot()
ax = figure.axes[0]
now = time.time()
dt64s = [datetime64(int(when), 's') for when in (now - 3600, now - 1800, now)]
dti = DatetimeIndex(dt64s, tz=tzlocal())
data = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
df = DataFrame(data, index=dti)  ## dt64s
df.plot(ax=ax)
figure.savefig('plot1.png')
```

This produces a plot with tick marks in UTC. The image is the same if I use plain `dt64s` above (which I kind of expect, since they're effectively UNIXtimes and matplotlib defaults to UTC). However, none of my experiments with things like `DateLocator` see to help either, or indeed make any change at all.

[image: Plot showing tick marks in UTC.]

***** a night's sleep and some more experimentation

I've made some progress. Here's an updated script:

```
import time
from dateutil.tz import tzlocal
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy import datetime64
from pandas import DatetimeIndex
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

figure = Figure(figsize=(7, 9))
figure.add_subplot()
ax = figure.axes[0]
now = time.time()
dt64s = [
    datetime64(int(when), 's')
    for when in (now + i * 1800 for i in range(-90, 1))
]
dti = DatetimeIndex(dt64s)  ##, tz=tzlocal())
print(dti)
data = {
    'a': [i for i, _ in enumerate(dt64s)],
    'b': [i + 2 for i, _ in enumerate(dt64s)]
}
df = DataFrame(data, index=dti)  ## dt64s
dfmt = DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z %Z", tz=tzlocal())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dfmt)
ax.set_title(f"Data from {dti[0]}..{dti[-1]}")
df.plot(ax=ax)
figure.savefig('plot1.png')
```

There are a few more significant changes:

- a longer time range to show a few days
- the `DatetimeIndex` no longer uses the `tz=` parameter
- I've added a `DateFormatter` to present dates in local time

In order:

The longer time range makes the zone effects more clear, in particular making the date and time parts clear, which aids looking at my local clock for comparison.

The `tz=` parameter of the `DatetimeIndex` does pretty much the opposite of what I imagined it would do. What I expected was that it would take the `datetime64` values as an offset from 1970 UTC (i.e. pure UNIX timestamp epoch) and produce localized Pandas datetime objects - those times rendered as calendar date/times in the local timezone. *However*, what it seems to do is to use the timezone as an offset for the epoch, and produces date/times *skewed* by my current timezone offset i.e. it means that the epoch reference is 1970 GMT+10 (my timezone), effectively making timestamps 10 hours adhead of what they should be.

Dropping the `tz=` parameter removes this skew. I get UTC date/times which are correct for my input timestamps.

The `DateFormatter` takes the nice UTC date/times in the index and *presents* them in my local timezone when labelling the tick marks. Partial victory.

What remains is to write a localtime aware `Locator` of some kind. The motivating graph for this question had tick marks at midnight UTC. I want to shift them to my local timezone midnight because I'm plotting solar power output and that is naturally aligned with my local sunlight.

[image: Current graph from the above code.]

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the correct result, we need :

- to import UNIX timestamps : use [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), specify the unit ('s') and the timezone ('utc'), as we are "tzaware"
- to convert the dataframe to local time : use [pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_convert](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_convert.html) with `tzlocal()`

This will give you the following code :

```
import time
from dateutil.tz import tzlocal
from pandas import DataFrame, DatetimeIndex, to_datetime
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

figure = Figure(figsize=(7, 4))
figure.add_subplot()
ax = figure.axes[0]
now = time.time()
utc_time = to_datetime([now - 3600, now - 1800, now],  unit='s', utc=True)
dti = DatetimeIndex(utc_time).tz_convert(tz=tzlocal())
data = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
df = DataFrame(data, index=dti)
df.plot(ax=ax)
figure.savefig('plot1.png')
```

You may use `DateFormatter` to get the display you want.